# Should hub have Browser installed

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Is it possible to run the hub in the VM machine which doesnt have broweser?. I have my RC machines with browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the WebDriver approach - there is HTMLUnitDriver which should do the job. See javadoc:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html

Answer (score 0):

The hub does not need a browser. You can even run the hub on a different OS than your RC machines.

For example we run our hub on linux, without any browsers, and our RC machines on Windows with browsers.

Comment: did u had browser installed in that linux machine?

Comment: "For example we run our hub on linux, without any browsers"